# which one is better strcasecmp or tolower/toupper + strcmp?

Tags: c

I have some code which uses `strcasecmp` quite a lot in one function (see version 1). So I was wondering if I should change it to upper- or lower-case and `strcmp` (like in version 2) to be c compliant and have a better performance, because I only need to convert it to upper- or lower-case once that way.

```
char pname[5]="TEST";
//version 1
if(strcasecmp(pname,"TEST")==0)
{
  printf("%s\n", pname);
}
//version 2
for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
{
    pname[i]=toupper(pname[i]);
}
if(strcmp(pname,"TEST")==0)
{
    printf("%s\n", pname);
}
```

Comment: In your example the second operator to the comparison is a constant, which makes another case for capitalizing the first operator. `strcasecmp` also deals with the, in this example, irrelevant case of  lower case letters in the second operator.

Comment: If by "c compliant" you mean "conforming to the C Standard" then you
cannot use `strcasecmp` because it is not in the Standard C Library. It
is a Posix extenstion.

Comment: Yes I mean "conforming to the C Standard by "c compliant".

Comment: That's apparently not C, but C++. This language has a string type: use it!

Comment: Just to point out that if you're dealing with non-ASCII characters then toupper+compare is not necessarily the same as case compare so in the sense of semantics case compare is better because there's no ambiguity on what you want the code to be doing.

Comment: @Michael: Next time post code for the langauge you tagged! C and C++ are different languages. Just in case you use a C++ compiler: that does make your code C++ code! Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. Try e.g.  `char *str = "Hello";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by better, you mean, better performance, i.e. fewer operations.

let's  say:

> x = time of tolower()/toupper()
>
> n = time of string[n] operation

also

> best case (quickest time to complete) = no match
>
> worst case (longest time to complete) = string match

these calculations assume we need tolower/toupper on only one string as shown in your code

**Version 1:** (strcasecmp)

> best case = 1 + x [i.e. one operation on to lower/upper on first character - no match]
>
> worst case = n + (x * n) [i.e. n operations of to lower/upper - string match]
>
> -- average = (n*(x+1) + x + 1)/2

**Version 2** (tolower/upper + strcmp)

> best case = 1 + (x * n) [i.e. n operations of to lower/upper on all character - no match]
>
> worst case = n [i.e. n operations on all characters]
>
> -- average = (1 + n*(x+1)) / 2

**Conclusion**

So the difference with version 2 is that is has improved the worst case, but in doing so has worsened the best case. However on average case, version 2 is quicker.

i.e. If you change the whole string to upper or lower case as in version 2 before hand, then you are having to loop through every character in the string already, which might not be required as the string may not match at all, adding extra operations that aren't required.

furthermore, depending on the compiler you are using, a for loop using indexes aren't particularly fast, you are quicker with:

```
   while (*chptr)
   {
      // do stuff with *chptr
      chptr++;
   }
```

for strings.

Comment: Do you really believe that in 2018 you need to manually optimize away a simple for-loop?

Comment: depends on the compiler of course. but the main point isn't the for loop optimization.

Comment: The for-loop was just a quick shot and can be ignored for this question.

Comment: There are some coding styles forbidding this kind of pointer arithmetic. The most prominent being MISRA. And wheter it's faster depends on the target architecture and compiler. Common patterns will compile to identical code on modern compilers. A programmer should concentrate writing maintainable code and leave optimisations to the compiler. Your "operation" calculation is pointless, too, as it depends on the features of the underlying architecture compiler (once more). The code in the question could eliminate the loops completely if the compiler can evaluate the outcome already.

Comment: I was more or less referring to how strcmp is implemented (see paul's answer). In that case, does that mean the use of strcmp is not 'MISRA compliant'? Or are there other libraries for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux kernel, [`strcmp`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.8/source/lib/string.c#L322) is implemented as below

```
int strcmp(const char *cs, const char *ct)
{
    unsigned char c1, c2;

    while (1) {
        c1 = *cs++;
        c2 = *ct++;
        if (c1 != c2)
            return c1 < c2 ? -1 : 1;
        if (!c1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[`strcasecmp`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.8/source/lib/string.c#L68) is implemented as below

```
int strcasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int c1, c2;

    do {
        c1 = tolower(*s1++);
        c2 = tolower(*s2++);
    } while (c1 == c2 && c1 != 0);
    return c1 - c2;
}
```

[`tolower`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.8/source/include/linux/ctype.h#L42) is implemented as below

```
static inline unsigned char __tolower(unsigned char c)
{
    if (isupper(c))
        c -= 'A'-'a';
    return c;
}
```

So I don't see much performance difference between your `version1` and your `version2`. Personally, I prefer `version1` than `version2`. It is much cleaner though. :)